# Create var from list of ID's JS

Tags: javascript

How do I go from here

```
<div id="cat" class="super"></div>
<div id="cat" class="super"></div>
<div id="bird" class="super"></div>
<div id="dog" class="super"></div>


var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName('super');
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    allElements[i].id && console.log(allElements[i].id);
}
```

which is giving me the list of ID's: cat dog bird ...

to dynamically assign personal `var` to every id from the class name `super`, not by it's number in the list/array but by its id like in an example

```
var new_el_1 = document.getElementById("cat");
var new_el_2 = document.getElementById("dog");
var new_el_3 = document.getElementById("bird");
...
```

So my basic question is how to get from my point to the example results.

Comment: You should be able to do it by using _eval_, but I don't understand why you need such code.

Comment: Why is this necessary? `document.getElementsByClassName()` already returns an array - can you not just access the array directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create variables that are accessible by their ID in the DOM, consider creating a single object whose properties map to the elements you want:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName('super');
var elementsMap = {};
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var id = allElements[i].id;
    if(allElements[i].id) {
        elementsMap[id] = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log(elementsMap[id]); //access each element by the id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please point how do I access it, or get the result in my example? @Bucket

Comment: @AndrewK It’s as simple as `elementsMap.cat` to retrieve the element with id `cat`. Alternatively if you have the id in a variable, use `elementsMap[myVar]` (`.cat` is just a short way of writing `['cat']`)

Comment: @AndrewK See edit - I added a `console.log()` output line to demonstrate how to retrieve elements from an array. The above comment is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.super').forEach((div,index) => div.setAttribute('id','array-element-'+index));
```

```html
<div class="super"></div>
<div class="super"></div>
<div class="super"></div>
<div class="super"></div>
<div class="super"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off storing these values in an array:

```js
let new_el = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= numElements; i++) {
  new_el[i] = document.getElementById(`array-element-${i}`);
}
```

Once stored, these can be accessed like this:

```js
new_el[2]  // returns the element #array-element-2
```

Comment: I updated my question, can you take a look at it again to verify your code, thank you @MTCoster

Comment: @AndrewK You’re better off with Bucket’s solution then.

Comment: Maybe, but in his code I can't see how it will get me to results in my example, sorry, new to JS. Can you help me out to figure it out to how to get it done? @MTCoster

Comment: The point of both mine and Bucket’s code is that you *don’t* want lots of variables like that. It is *technically possible*, but definitely isn’t idiomatic javascript.

Comment: You are right, but in my case this is exactly what I need @MTCoster

Comment: But ***why***? Why can’t you use an object or an array or another more *idiomatic* method of storing all these elements?

Comment: My previous comment was on my question, not on the code in my question, from the point where I'm standing I just need to get the result (all the ID's from the class name to the personal var like in the my example). Of course I would like to get this result most efficient way its possible, but I need that the results match my var example @MTCoster

Comment: I rethink my question to better explain my current situation and difficulties that I'm facing, my previous question was focusing on certain area and may mislead the ones who want to help me MTCoster @eds1999

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with MTCoster's answer that you'd better store these elements in an array. This is horrible code. That however doesn't answer your question. `window["variable_name"]` is what you're looking for. This will create individual variables.

```
for (let i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    window['new_el_' + i] = document.getElementById(allElements[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Why would you pollute the global scope like this? Bucket’s existing answer is effectively the same, but uses a new object to store all the elements.

Comment: If the OP wants to create variables with a by JS generated name, this is the way to do it. As I suggest he shouldn't, but this is how he would.